# e.preventDefault() or return false failed to stop file input to open

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

How to stop file upload windows from opening when it's uploading the file?

```
export default class Upload extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            filename: null,
            isLoading: false
        }

    }

    trigger_upload_input = () => {
        document.getElementById("browse-file").click();
    }

    handleOnChange = (e) => {
        if(e.target.files[0]) {
            this.setState({filename: e.target.files[0].name, isLoading: true});
            var that = this;

            setTimeout(function(){
                that.setState({isLoading: false})
            },3000)
        }

    }

    handleInputClicked = (e) => {
        if(this.state.isLoading){
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    }

    render() {
        const { isLoading } = this.state;
        return(
            <div className="upload">
                <div>
                    <input onClick={this.handleInputClicked} onChange={this.handleOnChange} type="file" id="browse-file"/>
                    {this.state.filename && <span>{this.state.filename}</span>}
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

The loading indicator work but when I try to click on the input again e.preventDefault() doesn't stop the file window to open, tried `return false` it doesn't solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try `e.stopPropagation()`, may be it will help ([event.stopPropagation()](https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/)).

**Update**

Looks, like a `disabled` attribute could be added with onChange handler. This will prevent from dialog opening. This attribute can be removed after loading is complete.

Comment: May be just add a `disabled` attribute to the input to prevent it from being clickable?

Answer (score 0):

you can <strike>hack</strike> browser behaviour like this

```
e.target.disabled = true;
setTimeout(function () { e.target.disabled = false; }, 500);
```